# Logcat not showing logs in android studio chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

From the last 3 days, I try to load logs in logcat window but for some reason, I am unable to track the issue and there is no log printed.

I am useing Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Please have a look logcat image.

[image]

Comment: Try clearing cache and restart android studio.

Comment: try `invalidate and restart` from file -> invalidate caches... -> invalidate and restart

Answer (score 5):

After spending too much time to loading `LOGCAT` issue I am able to resolve it in a very simple way.

Before you try any `SOLUTION`, create a new project and check `LOGCAT` window is printing the device log or not!

If your new project prints the device log it means your older project has some issue. To solve that issue you follow these steps.

1. Close the project and remove the project from the recent project.
2. Jump to directory/folder in Mac/Windows.
3. Remove `.idea` and `.gradle` directory/folder from Mac/Windows.
4. Open the project again and its works.

Comment: Thanks it worked. It's so frustrating sometimes that updating Android Studio brings up so many new bugs.